# redirect users based on their logged in or not

Tags: wordpress, xcode, logging, redirect

if a not logged in user tries to access a specific page they will be redirected to another specific page.

How can I do that?

if someone can, please suggest me some code. because I don't like to add a new plugin for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in functions php:

function redirect_page() {

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
    ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $protocol = 'https://';
    }
    else {
    $protocol = 'http://';
}

$currenturl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$currenturl_relative = wp_make_link_relative($currenturl);

switch ($currenturl_relative) {

    case '[from slug]':
        $urlto = home_url('[to slug]');
        break;

    default:
        return;

}

if ($currenturl != $urlto)
    exit( wp_redirect( $urlto ) );
```

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_page' );

Answer (score 0):

this has been asked and answered quite a few times. 
this is a good response: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131926/118903